# Get html tag in IInternetProtocolRoot::Start

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, com, activex

Is it possible to get html tag which initiated the call `IInternetProtocolRoot::Start`?

```
STDMETHODIMP MyProtocol::Start( LPCWSTR szUrl, 
    IInternetProtocolSink* pOIProtSink,
    IInternetBindInfo* pOIBindInfo, 
    DWORD grfPI, HANDLE_PTR dwReserved )
{
    LPCWSTR tag = ???

    ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that tag must be involved in this operation? What if write protocol to the address bar?

Comment: I did not say that he must :) In the case of the address bar html tag will not of course. But when MSHTML parses the page and find the tag (e.g. <img>), it initiates loading (image in case of <img>). It would be nice to get this tag.

Comment: I think that not possible for pluggable protocol determine source tag. This is my opinion. Maybe another interface helps you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. Now, why would you need this? What actual problem are you trying to solve?